# How to redirect to the API's entry point without hardcoding the path?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I've tried calling reverse with the install of the Api to no avail. Using the shell to determine the name of the RegexpURLPattern I determine that the name was api_v2_top_level but calling reverse('api_v2_top_level_') doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
# How I determined the name of the view.
In [3]: v2_api.urls
Out[3]:
[<RegexURLPattern api_v2_top_level ^(?P<api_name>v2)/$>,
 <RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^(?P<api_name>v2)/>,
 <RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^(?P<api_name>v2)/>,
 <RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^(?P<api_name>v2)/>]

from tastypie.api import Api
v2_api = Api(api_name='v2')
v2_api.register(...)
...
from api.urls import v2_api
In [4]: v2_api.urls[0]
Out[4]: <RegexURLPattern api_v2_top_level ^(?P<api_name>v2)/$>

In [5]: v2_api.urls[0].name
Out[5]: u'api_v2_top_level'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse('api_v2_top_level', kwargs={'api_name': 'v2'})` should do the trick.